# I'm trying to limit rsyslog outgoing to Emerg, crit , alert and error but having difficulty

Tags: linux, syslog

This is the line i have:

*.=emerg,crit,alert,error @@syslogserver:1468

What i'm receiving is all messages. Is there anything wrong with this syntax?

Comment: Are you using sysklogd, syslog-ng or rsyslog?

Comment: I'm using rsyslog

Answer (score 0):

I don't use rsyslog, but it claims to faithfully reimplement the sysklogd config format. In that, commas do not separate priorities, only facilities; you can do `daemon,kern.info` as a shorthand for `daemon.info,kern.info` (as a consequence, `daemon.emerg,kern.info` would silently drop the priority spec for the former). To separate facility.priority pairs, use a semicolon; to list multiple priorities, either specify multiple pairs (in ascending order: `*.=err;*.=crit;*.=alert;*.=emerg`) or just use the default "specified priorities and higher" behaviour: `*.err` will match all messages at or above `LOG_ERR`, from all facilities.